# pointer incrementation and assignment

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

In the following two lines in C:

```
int* a = (int *)calloc(automata_size, sizeof(int));

int* b = (a++);
```

I found that a and b share the same address. This is not the case if we have

```
int* a = (int *)calloc(automata_size, sizeof(int));

int* b = a + 1;
```

why?

Comment: Because a++ and a+1 have a different value. Review the definition of the postincrement operator.

Comment: Isn't it the case that a++ and a=a+1 are equivalent expressions?

Comment: No, they return different values. Review the definition of the postincrement operator.

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies that this might've ended up a simpler explanation than may be appropriate for the website.

Comment: `int* b = a + 1` does _not_ alter `a`. But, `int* b = (*a++)` does. It is the same as `int* b = a++`. This is the _postincrement_ form. To get the effect that you want, do: `int *b = ++a`. This is the _preincrement_ form. With postincrement, `a` and `b` will be different, but with preincrement they will be the same afterwards

Comment: Thanks for asking. In the first case you cannot have compared the addresses *after* the assignment to `b`, since `a` was incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The pre- and postfix `++` operators have a *result* and a *side effect*.

The *result* of `a++` is the value of `a` prior to the increment.  The *side effect* is that `a` is incremented.  Thus, if `a` is something like `0x4000` and `sizeof (int)` is 4, then after executing

```
int *b = a++;
```

the value of `b` will be `0x4000` and the value of `a` will be `0x4004`<sup>1</sup>.

The *result* of `++a` is the value of `a` plus 1.  The *side effect* is that `a` is incremented.  This time, the value of both `b` and `a` will be `0x4004`.

Note: you will want to retain the original value returned from `calloc` somehow so that you can properly `free` it later.  If you pass the modified value of `a` to `free`, you will (most likely) get a runtime error.

---

1. Pointer arithmetic depends on the size of the pointed-to type.  Applying `++` or adding 1 to a pointer advances it to point to the *next object* of the given type.  On most systems in use today, an `int` is 4 bytes wide, so using `++` on a pointer adds 4 to the pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

So my advice is google post-increment and pre-increment. Pre-increment (`++a`) is:

```
b = ++a;
```

and is the same as:

```
a = a + 1;
b = a;
```

Where as post-increment:

```
b = a++;
```

is the same as

```
b = a;
a = a + 1;
```

this applies to pointers as well as integers.